# WPF Datagrid updates on cell edit

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

WPF Datagrid updates on cell edit..
I am giving ItemsSource of datagrid as a List....
when i edit the datagrid it automatically reflects in the List..I don't want to update it automatically, I have a save button upon clicking that it should save the List.

Answer (score 1):

Set UpdateSourceTrigger to explicit in your binding

```
{Binding Path=someProp, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}
```